# How can I save the contents of a mysqli_result object?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hey guys Im currently trying to debug some code for a mysqli encapsulation class. Ive run into a problem described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php#100530) have tried a few solutions with this being the latest iteration and (doesn't seem to work):

```
$this->result = new stdClass();
foreach($res = $this->conn->query($sql) as $key => $value) {
    $this->result->$key = $value;
}
```

If anyone knows a way to store the results somehow or create a system with pointers and $result->free_result(); bring called at sometime it would be much appreciated. Im a little stumped and very short for time.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT as of right now my original implementation seems to be working not sure if this will hold true through testing. Currently I have a custom $this->query() function calling mysqli->query and storing the results in $this->result, however under some circumstances it seems $this->result becomes unset. Going to keep testing/debugging what I have and see if it happens again. Thanks to those who answered :)

EDIT 2 Through a fair bit of trial and error Ive traced the issue I was having back to a SQL query behaving oddly. It seems its not possible to store the resulting object from mysqli::query() without issue(?).

Comment: if you want to store the result in the object you need to create a class with variables for every field your queering and then store it in the object

Comment: I don't suppose this is failing because of the typo?  kek => $key

Comment: Should `$this->result->kek` be `$this->result->$key`?

Comment: Typo in the question I didnt copy/paste from the source so no :/

Comment: @COLDTOLD want to toss me some clarification / a pseudo code example cold?

Comment: @user1195999: I fail to see where you are even fetching rows.

Comment: I was not trying to fetch rows just transfer the contents of the mysqli_result object to a variable something that the comment linked in the question stated was not working as expected. (Seemingly works now however)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example coding isn't fetching rows. You'll need to do that and one of the options is to [fetch as objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php):

```
$this->rows = array();

$res = $this->conn->query($sql);

while ($obj = $res->fetch_object()) {
    $this->rows[] = $obj;
}

echo $this->rows[0]->id; // assuming you have a column named id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare properties ahead of time in PHP classes. Just assign it dynamically:

```
foreach($res = $this->conn->query($sql) as $key => $value) {
    $this->result->$key = $value;
}
```

That will create a property with the same name as the value of $key. Just keep in mind that if $key has spaces in the name you won't be able to access the property the usual way. For example:

```
$key = 'Hello World';
$this->result->$key = 'Hi!';
// now this won't work even though Hello World is the property name:
echo $this->result->Hello World;
// instead do:
echo $this->result->$key;
// or access it like an associative array
echo $this->result['Hello World'];
```

Comment: Tried this and it did not seem to work, Ill try it again and look everything I have to see if theres something else messing with it. Also i just prefer to declare variables non dynamic style for clarity (my background's mostly C/C++) If I can declare something in non dynamic fashion inside 5 seconds I normally do :)

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. Instead do: `echo $this->result->{'Hello World'};` Regardless, may be better to create specific class with the required public properties ahead of time (or use getters and setters instead).

Comment: I agree that declaring the variables is preferred. I always declare them for the sake of clarity, but if you're pulling from a result set for which you don't always know the column names then this helps.

Comment: I cannot argue that there are indeed benefits to dynamic typing :)